# python requests.get keep erroring out when adding a variable

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a simple python script and `requests.get` keeps giving me problems when I try to add the IP dynamically

If I do this it works:

```
r = requests.get("http://123.123.123.123")
```

If I do this it fails:

```
r = requests.get("http://" + ipnum)
```

here is the full code

```
#!/usrbin/env python
import subprocess
import requests

ipnum = subprocess.check_output(["hostname", "-i"])
ipstr = str(ipnum)

r = requests.get ("http://" + ipstr)

if r.status_code == 200
    print("Web1:"+ str(r))
else:
    print("Web1:"+ str(r))
```

Comment: Have you checked that ipstr does not contains other thing than IP address like space ?

Comment: please add the error message

Comment: What version of python are ou running and what is the exact error message?

Comment: ok how did i miss that that is exactly what it was doing it had a space at the begining that i didnt notice thanks

Comment: You can use the socket lib to get the ip `print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))`

Answer (score 4):

When I did my testing, I discovered that `check_output` adds a new line to the end.  Try using `ipstr.strip()` instead of `ipstr` when you add it to "http://"